# How to make IMAP sign-in attempts more secure using PHP?

Tags: php, imap, email-client, gmail-imap, php-imap

I'm using the PHP [imap extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) to read emails from a gmail account but when I tried it the first time I got an email from google telling me that it had blocked the sign-in because it was "from an app that may put your account at risk" and that "Google will continue to block sign-in attempts from the app you're using because it has known security problems or is out of date" . I had to go to the settings on gmail and manually "allow access to less secure apps". So my question is how do I make my sign-in attempts more secure so that I don't have to "allow access to less secure apps"?

Comment: Implement OAUTH2.